# adding buttons with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Im trying to add buttons to a web page along with values in a table, althought I cant even get passed the blank page, whats wrong with my code, and can I set a variable on button press?

php:

```
<?php
$sql_link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '12buckle', 'GameData');
$SetHomework = mysqli_query($sql_link, "SELECT * FROM tblClassHomework WHERE ClassID   ='".$_SESSION['ClassID']."'");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Deadline</th>
<th>Comment</th>
<th>Play</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SetHomework))
{
$SetHomework = mysqli_query($sql_link, "SELECT * FROM tblHomework WHERE     HomeworkID='".$row['HomeworkID']."'");
$Homework = mysqli_fetch_array($SetHomework);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $Homework['HomeworkName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Deadline'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Comment'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><form action='index.php' method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit"     value="Play"></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

My php is inside the html file the table will be presented in

Comment: you are using mysqli and ignoring prepared statements..Heresy!!

Comment: Why is your table name prefixed with `tbl`? That seems horribly redundant.

Comment: oh yeah this is my first forray into php and database structure as a whole, i guess those prefixes are dumb, but I want to fix my error first before changing more stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error on this line:

```
echo "<td><form action='index.php' method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit"     value="Play"></form></td>";
```

You are prematurely ending the string to be `echo`ed by using double quotes within the string. One way of fixing this would be to use only single quotes within your double quotes, like:

```
echo "<td><form action='index.php' method='post'><input type='submit' name='submit'     value='Play'></form></td>";
```

If you haven't enabled the display of error messages, you will encounter a blank screen when there is a syntax error. You can enable them by setting the following at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you should be using prepared statements to protect you from MYSQL injection. On your line:

```
$SetHomework = mysqli_query($sql_link, "SELECT * FROM tblClassHomework WHERE ClassID   ='".$_SESSION['ClassID']."'");
```

You are concatenating the value of `$_SESSION['ClassID']`. Instead of this you should be using prepared statements. Change your code to something like this:

```
$SetHomework = mysqli_query($sql_link, "SELECT * FROM tblClassHomework WHERE ClassID   = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($SetHomework, 's', $_SESSION['ClassID']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($SetHomework);
```

The `'i'` is a placeholder for an integer. If `$_SESSION['ClassID']` is a different type, you should change the placeholder accordingly. See the [bind_param documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more details on that.

Comment: @MrGears No problem. I have also just added some detail on prepared statements that you should take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`